# Protractor: Can not access variables in closure defined in parent function

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have following code in one of my JS files.

```
// test/lib/UserHelper.js

'use strict';
var Firebase = require('firebase');

exports.createUser = function (email, password) {
  browser.executeAsyncScript(function (done) {
    var $firebaseSimpleLogin = angular.inject(['ng', 'firebase']).get('$firebaseSimpleLoging');
    var firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://urltoapplication.firebaseio.com');
    var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseRef);

    auth.$createUser(email, password);

    done();
  });
};
```

I call it within my test like:

```
// test/settings/company.spec.js

'use strict';
var user = require('../lib/UserHelper');

describe('company specs', function () {

  beforeEach(function () {
    user.createUser('test@test.com', 'test');
  });
});
```

The call to `user.createUser('test@test.com', 'test');` in the `beforeEach` callback fails with `UnknownError: email is not defined` at `auth.$createUser(email, password);`.

Why is `email` variable not accessible in the callback function? Can it be made possible to propagate arguments passed to the closing function that were passed to `createUser` function?

---

This is what worked for me based on answer of Andres D.

```
exports.createUser = function (data) {
  browser.executeAsyncScript(function (data, done) {
    var $firebaseSimpleLogin = angular.inject(['ng', 'firebase']).get('$firebaseSimpleLoging');
    var firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://urltoapplication.firebaseio.com');
    var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseRef);

    auth.$createUser(data.email, data.password);

    done();
  }, data);
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example that I used during an angular meetup:

You can only pass one argument to executeAsyncScript. I would recommend you to pass an object if you need to pass more than one value:

```
module.exports = {
  create: function(data) {
    return browser.executeAsyncScript(function(data, callback) {
      var api = angular.injector(['ProtractorMeetupApp']).get('apiService');
      api.member.save(data, function(newItem) {
        callback(newItem._id);
      })
    }, data);
  }
};

create({email: 'sdf@sdf.com', password: 'sfd'}).then(function(response){
  // Handle response here.
})
```

https://github.com/andresdominguez/protractor-meetup/blob/master/test/e2e/api-helper.js#L12

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that executeAsyncScript is actually performed in the browser that selenium is running, and therefor does not pass variables from the above scope through it.

I'm not sure if anyone knows a way to pass variables through this way.